# How To Implement OAuth 2.0 in laravel 5.4 from scratch

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, orm, oauth-2.0

I am new to **laravel 5.4** and I want to implement my application using **OAuth 2.0**.I had read laravel 5.4 documentation, but I can't get a clear idea about **OAuth2.0** using **laravel 5.4**.

Please, guys, somebody have any document or website link about **OAuth2.0 for laravel 5.4**! Share with me.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at Laravel Passport documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport

Everything is clear and simple in this documentation. But as the disclaimer says:

> This documentation assumes you are already familiar with OAuth2. If you do not know anything about OAuth2, consider familiarizing yourself with the general terminology and features of OAuth2 before continuing.

Comment: i had go through that above link.but i dont get a clear knowledge about Oauth2.0 in laravel5.4 .plz somebody give a alternate resource for OAuth2.0